# How can I remove "Number Stored as Text" prompt upon Export To Excel using EPPLUS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel, epplus

I have export my gridview data to excel using EPPLUS, but however for a few columns I have this green tag "Number Stored as Text" prompt after opening the excel file that was exported.

**How can I code in my export to excel codes to change the datatype/convert to number for a specific column starting from the 2nd row of a specified column since the 1st row is header?**

Comment: In your `DataTable` `DataType` set it as `Int`. It will not show.. The reason it show because in Excel will give assumption if only `Number` in the cell will ask you to stored it as `Number` rather than `Text`

Comment: I have tried setting it as int, however due to the fact that my header is a string it can convert the whole column to int. thus how can I exclude the header which is the first row of excel to be excluded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code here. 
Check the added code..

**EDITED**

I have change the variable name for your `DataTable` assuming the thing what you are doing.. `GridView1` is a `GridView UI Control` and you put the `DataTable Name` as `GridView1`, the code might be confuse on what is `GridView1`

```
protected void EXPORT_BUTTON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Added Code
    int parseValue;
    bool isInt;

    ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();

    ExcelWorksheet Grid = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("ORSA ASSESSMENTS");

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        // Update Type
        dt.Columns.Add("column" + i.ToString(), typeof(int));
    }

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            row.Cells[j].Text = row.Cells[j].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");

            // Added Code
            isInt = int.TryParse(row.Cells[j].Text.Trim(), out parseValue);

            // Added Code
            if (isInt) 
                dr["column" + j.ToString()] = parseValue;

        }

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }


    Grid.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);

    using (ExcelRange rng = Grid.Cells["A1:Z1"])
    {
        rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
    }

    Grid.Cells[ORSA.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();



    var FolderPath = ServerName + DirectoryLocation + DirectoryFolder + ExportsFolder;
    var filename = ExcelName + @"_" + ".xlsx";
    var filepath = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(FolderPath, filename));

    Response.Clear();
    package.SaveAs(filepath);
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ";");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
    Response.TransmitFile(filepath.FullName);
    Response.End();

}
```

This is the sample i mocked up and is a working example

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // Create Column
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            dt.Columns.Add("column" + i, typeof(int));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(i, i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4);

        GenerateExcel(dt);
    }
}

private void GenerateExcel(DataTable dt)
{
    using (ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

        ws.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light18);

        pkg.SaveAs(new FileInfo("C:\\Test.xlsx"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nic, Do you have any ide a how to set the a all border to all the cells populated in excel?

Comment: @JamesBoer you can use Style in your LoadFromDataTable....
Example like
`ws.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light18);` You can easily find a Style by create table in Excel then hover the Style Number of it

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problems. As [Ordel Eraki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303254/orel-eraki) said: do not stringify the value:

```
workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = 2; // Value is object
```

<strike>workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = 2.ToString()</strike>

Answer (score 2):

You should save you string as an `int` not a `string`. Whenever you want your cell to be as number, just cast your cell input as `int`.

That means, when populating your data, be sure to populate it as `int`.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but it did not change anything

Comment: The reason is because I do also have other columns(not shown in the image) their data type is a string. thus if I would to change to your codes. My string will appear to have the error thn. thanks

Comment: I understand also for the method you are using, I will see an error that I cannot implicitly change string to int

Comment: Hi, there I have tried populating as int but it failed.